# how i can pass sub folder-name and get result in response using node js api & SolidBucket?

Tags: node.js, azure

i am using solid bucket npm package to create an api for cloud storages. i am using to azure blob storage to getListFiles. folder name  passing to the provider api its return the file list. what i am facing the issue is the i have sub folders in my azure blob storage that sub folder name send to api its returns the

> result code is 0

and

> response body **no content**

The Code is:

```
const SolidBucket = require('solid-bucket')

let provider = new SolidBucket('azure', {
    accountName: 'accountName',
    accountKey: 'accountKey'
})

let bucketName = 'example'
provider.getListOfFiles(bucketName).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.log(resp.message) 
        // Output: The list of objects was fetched successfully from bucket "example"
    }
}).catch((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 400){
        console.log(resp.message)
        // Output: Some error coming from the provider...
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @NarayanSharma i am sended the bucketname(foldername) is my sub folder name its return the result code 0 and response body showing No Content

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `bucketname` value should be the container name on Azure Blob Storage, not the virtual sub-folder name in a container.

So I used my azure storage account name & key and my `test` container to run the same code with an additional code `console.log(resp)` at the front of `if (resp.status === 200)`, the result is as below.

[image]

It's corresponding with the same file structure in my `test` container via Azure Storage Explorer.

[image]

Comment: i am also getting the same result. my doubt is how to pass the subfolder like azcopy in the parameter as a bucketName. Is it possible?

Comment: ＠SandySanthosh I'm afraid that's not possible by `solid-bucket` which just realized common features for cross-platform, not implement the Azure Blob Storage [`List Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) API with the prefix of subfolder name to list files. I recommended you can directly use the `List Blobs` API of Azure Storage SDK for Node with the subfolder name prefix to do that.